# How to get a UITableView method to run before another override method?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

Below is my code. After testing the app for a bit I realized that the `didSelectRowAtIndex` is run AFTER `prepareForSegue`. How can I get `didSelectRowAtIndex` to run first.

If the answer involves threading, I have no idea how that works so please explain. Thank-you.

```
 import UIKit

class AvailableShifts: UITableViewController {

    var shiftData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var shiftID: String!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

//        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
//        
//        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "refreshList", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        loadData()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return shiftData.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:AvailableShiftsCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as AvailableShiftsCell

        let shift: PFObject = shiftData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

        cell.locationLabel.text = shift.objectForKey("Location") as String?
        cell.shiftLabel.text = shift.objectForKey("Shift") as String?
        cell.dateLabel.text = shift.objectForKey("Date") as String?
        cell.id.text = shift.objectId

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let shift: PFObject = shiftData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
        shiftID = shift.objectId
        println(shiftID)

    }

    func loadData () {


        var getShifts = PFQuery(className: "Shifts")

        getShifts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                self.shiftData.removeAllObjects()

                for object in objects {

                    self.shiftData.addObject(object)
                }

                let array: NSArray = self.shiftData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects

                self.shiftData = array.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func refreshButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        loadData()
    }

//    func refreshList() {
//        
//        loadData()
//        
//        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
//        
//    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "details") {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ShiftOverview;

            svc.shiftID = shiftID

            println(shiftID)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Downvote with no explanation why. Wonderful.

Comment: You say that you want didSelectRowAtIndex to run first and say that it already runs first? I don't understand what you want to do here.

Comment: Sorry...I meant after. Stupid me.

Comment: Why would you want prepareForSegue to run first? It is called when you are transitioning view controllers so why would it be called before the current one is resolved?

Comment: I changed my question to say "After". Right now, prepareforsegue is run before didselectrow. I need a value from didselectrow to pass to another VC (where prepareforsegue comes into play). The way it is now, the code passes a nil value to the next VC because didselectrow still hasn't gotten the required value.

Comment: Are you triggering this segue by your uitableviewcell being pressed?

Comment: Yup...that's probably my problem right?

Comment: But I don't know how to call an override function. It just goes on its own.

Comment: "How can I get didSelectRowAtIndex to run first" You need to change your desires. Understand this: it's a framework. The order in which it calls things is the order in which it calls things. Accept reality. Your job is to arrange your architecture so that that order is okay with you. Actually, you should not be depending on _any_ particular order, because you never know, things may change without notice (unless they are explicitly documented to happen in a certain order, and even that has proven to be no guarantee when it comes to Apple).

Comment: You could set up segue from view controller to destination in story board (control drag from view controller to destination... Not from cell to destination). Give this segue an identifier. Then in your didselectrowatindexpath function call performSegueWithIdentifier after you set the shiftID.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all for your application. If the segue is made from the cell, then the sender argument in `prepareForSegue:sender:` will be the cell. You can use the table view method `indexPathForCell:` to get the `indexPath`, and thus the `PFObject` you need.